# Generate random numbers list with limit on each element and on total

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

Assume I have a list of values, for example:

```
limits = [10, 6, 3, 5, 1]
```

For every item in `limits`, I need to generate a random number less than or equal to the item. However, the catch is that the sum of elements in the new random list must be equal to a specified total.

For example if `total = 10`, then one possible random list is:

```
random_list = [2, 1, 3, 4, 0]
```

where you see `random_list` has same length as `limits`, every element in `random_list` is less than or equal to the corresponding element in `limits`, and `sum(random_list) = total`.

How to generate such a list? I am open (and prefer) to use numpy, scipy, or pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Found what I was looking for: The [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) which is similar to the binomial, but without replacement.

The distribution [available in numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.multivariate_hypergeometric.html):

```
import numpy as np

gen = np.random.Generator(np.random.PCG64(seed))
random_list = gen.multivariate_hypergeometric(limits, total)

# array([4, 4, 1, 1, 0])
```

Also to make sure I didn't misunderstand the distribution did a sanity check with 10 million samples and check that the maximum is always within the limits

```
res = gen.multivariate_hypergeometric(limits, total, size=10000000) 

res.max(axis=0)

# array([10,  6,  3,  5,  1])
```

which is same as `limits`.