# How to create a random list that satisfy a condition (in one try)?

Tags: python, list, numpy, random

I have written the following code to generate a **random** list. I want the list to have elements between **0** and **500**, but the **summation** of all elements does not exceed **1300**. I dont know how to continue my code to do that. I have written other codes; for example, to create a list of random vectors and then pick among those that satisfy the condition. But here I want to create such a list in one try.

```
nv = 5
bounds = [(0, 500), (0, 500), (0, 500), (0, 500), (0, 500)]
var =[]
for j in range(nv):
    var.append(random.uniform(bounds[j][0], bounds[j][1]))
    summ = sum(var)
    if summ > 1300:
        ????
```

Comment: Can you use a package? `numpy` [makes it simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74670818/generate-random-numbers-list-with-limit-on-each-element-and-on-total).

Comment: oh yes, but at the end I need a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `append` until after you've validated the value.

Use `while len() < maxLen` so that you can handle repeat attempts.

You don't really need `nv` since `len(bounds)` dictates the final value of `len(var)`.

`len(var)` is also the next index of the `var` list that is unused so you can use that to keep track of where you are in `bounds`.

A running sum is more efficient than using `sum()` on every check. (Though on small lists, it's not going to make a noticeable difference.)

The `*` in the `.uniform()` call splits a list into individual arguments. ([Asterisks in Python: what they are and how to use](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/) them seems like a good tutorial on the subject.)

```py
import random

bounds = [(0, 500), (0, 500), (0, 500), (0, 500), (0, 500)]
var = []
runningSum = 0
while len(var) < len(bounds):
    sample = random.uniform(*bounds[len(var)])
    if runningSum + sample < 1300:
        runningSum += sample
        var.append(sample)

print(repr(var))
```

Comment: Thank you @Ourborus. this code has a small issue. when I rerun the code, sometimes, it stucks and does not produce the result. and I need to terminate my run.

Comment: @pymn I'm unable to reproduce this even after thousands of runs. See my [replit](https://replit.com/@ouroborus/WealthyImaginaryLinuxkernel). (There are times where the intermediate sum ends up very close to but not over 1300. This means the next value may have to be retried a lot before it produces a value small enough. It could only hang if the lower bound is >0.)

Answer (score 0):

Without the aid of *numpy* you could do this:

```
from random import uniform

def func1():
    LIMIT = 1_300
    bounds = [(0, 500), (0, 500), (0, 500), (0, 500), (0, 500)]

    while sum(result := [uniform(lo, hi) for lo, hi in bounds]) > LIMIT:
        pass

    return result
```